# Heroku django program deployed,but returned a 400 error

Tags: python, django, heroku

The thing is,I wrote a very simple django blog.And I put it on Github.Then I tried to deploy it on Heroku.When I finished it,I only saw 400 Bad Request.I'm confused.The log is here:

`2018-03-13T11:56:51.929117+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=guoguoblog.herokuapp.com request_id=85b467df-9cd5-4bae-8cd8-e33a9c89d1a9 fwd="112.9.115.29" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=20ms status=400 bytes=154 protocol=https`

`2018-03-13T11:56:51.928540+00:00 app[web.1]: [13/Mar/2018 19:56:51] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 400 26`

And repeat again when I flush my page.
What can I do?

Oh,this is my github project.https://github.com/qwedc001/DjangoBlog

Can anybody help me?

Eric

Comment: Note that it's insecure to post your `SECRET_KEY` on GitHub, and you shouldn't use SQLite on Heroku - use PostgreSQL instead.

Comment: Thanks for notes.I'll fix that problem.But...emm,I ....don't know how to use PostgreSQL.

Comment: Heroku with PostgreSQL is a standard setup. You should hopefully be able to find a guide or tutorial if you search.

Comment: K. I know.I'll try to find out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add `guoguoblog.herokuapp.com` to your `ALLOWED_HOSTS` setting. At the moment, it looks as if you have `guoguoblog.heroku.com` instead.

Comment: Ohh,my fault.Thanks.I'll try again

Comment: But...emm...New question,the static files(css,js) don't work now.It's very ugly.

Comment: That’s a separate issue, so I can’t help with that. Whitenoise is a popular choice for Django + Heroku.